# Exception Handling Problem with OSError [Errno 22]

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-3.7

The [3.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) states that we should handle OSError exceptions as such:

```
except OSError as err:
    print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
```

I still get an error with program exit when I do exactly that.  The error is:

```
   File "F:/working/workfile.py", line 55, in main
    OutFile = open(FileName, 'w')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'bad<>file.txt'
```

Full, relevant area of code:

```
def main():
        InvalidInput = True

        while InvalidInput:
                #Start Exception handling
                try:
                        # Ask user for how many random numbers to create
                        NumberCount = int(input('How many numbers do you want to generate?'))

                        # Ask the user where the created numbers are to be stored
                        # Error out if invalid characters are used
                        FileName = input('Where do you want the files to be written to?')

                # Catch the error if invalid characters are used

                except OSError as err:
                        print("OS error: {0}".format(err))
                        print ('Please enter a valid path/filename.')
                        InvalidInput = True

                except IOError:
                        print ('Please enter a valid path/filename.')
                        InvalidInput = True

                except ValueError:
                        print ('Invalid number.  Please enter only integers')
                        InvalidInput = True

                else:
                        InvalidInput = False
                        OutFile = open(FileName, 'w')
                        for Number in range (NumberCount):
                                # Call the function(s) for generating random numbers
                                # and writing to the output file
                                ReturnNumber = RandomNumbers.RandomWriter ()
                                OutFile.write (str(ReturnNumber))
                                OutFile.write ("\n")

                                print ('Writing ', ReturnNumber)

                        # Close the file when finished
                        OutFile.close()

        print ('Closing the open file.')

main()
```

Typing a filename with valid characters works just fine.  I need the program to not crash out, and hand this exception.  Any advice on what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: What's the code that's producing the exception look like? Are you sure that the line throwing the exception is within your try:/except block?

Comment: I'm not sure of anything.  It was not throwing OSErrors when I was attempting to put invalid characters in the filename.  Unsure what changed.

Comment: Looks like the line that throws the error isn't inside a try/catch block. It's in one of the error handling branches. Put the line `out_file = open(file_name, 'w')` inside the block beneath your comment `#Catch the error...`.. but make sure your indentation is with the code and not the comment. Move the for loop up there with it.

Comment: BTW, naming conventions in Python are lowercase-and-underscores for local variables and function names, and PascalCase for class names.

Comment: Thanks for your commentary and help, Todd; That worked.  Extra set of eyes and me needing a break, I believe.  Please reply and I will mark as the answer.  Also, what naming convention am I using?  I really don't know, I have no clue.

Comment: okay.. hold on.

Comment: Love it, post a question on here, and the downvotes come pouring because it's not a cool enough problem.  Stackoverflow is like crack - you know it's bad, but it fixes your immediate concerns, so you just can't stay away.   But you always end up hating yourself the next day.

Comment: heh.. better than being downvoted at work during a code review =)

Comment: One downvote is a "downvotes come pouring"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that deals with opening and reading from the file should be within the try block of the try/except statement like so:

```
try:
    # ... preceding code...

    OutFile = open(FileName, 'w')
    for Number in range (NumberCount):
        # Call the function(s) for generating random numbers
        # and writing to the output file
        ReturnNumber = RandomNumbers.RandomWriter ()
        OutFile.write (str(ReturnNumber))
        OutFile.write ("\n")

        print ('Writing ', ReturnNumber)

    # Close the file when finished
    OutFile.close()
except:
```